# Mysql search in concatinated string

Tags: mysql, where-in, sql-in

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE n_dummy (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `values` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `n_dummy` (id, `values`) VALUES
(2, '2,10'),
(10, '2,10')
(3,  '7,3');
```

Look like this:

```
id | values
-----------
2  | 2,10
10 | 2,10
3  | 7,3
```

[Fiddle included.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b96a4/2)

The first column is the integer to be searched in string from `values` column.

Note: Example is too simplified and looks stupid. Refactoring table structure is not the way. Only sql query with standard functions and procedures.

I want to search integer value in string, concatenated from integers with `,` separator.

I expects MySQL to do this with `IN` operator:
SELECT id
FROM n_dummy
WHERE id IN(`values`);

And result would be `2`, `10` and `3`. But MySQL returns only `2`, the second and other values is not searchable with IN operator with string.

How to search integer in concatenated string using sql-query and prebuild routines?

Comment: doing that in relational database, `looks stupid`; agreed.

Comment: Question is too simplified version of very big query (%), which consists from a huge ammount of subqueries, so the actual tables are created dynamically, not with insert statement.

Comment: The main purpose of question for me is to know, how to find integer in dynamically created concatenated with separator string (it is formed via `CONCAT_WS` function and many `CASE` operators, not plain sql-query)

Comment: The sqlfiddle doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Some problems with Sqlfiddle stability...

Comment: Sorry completely wrong design. One does not store comma separated values in columns

Comment: Values is not stored actually, whey formed dynamically based on complicated case condition.

Bad design, ok, let it be so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this brother

```
SELECT * FROM `n_dummy` WHERE concat(',',`values`,',') LIKE concat('%',',',`id`,',','%')
```